# Undefined method add_to_base

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

I'm working with activemerchant and it raise me this error when validating the card is this ok in rails 3? thank you in advance more power to all

```
belongs_to :reservation

  attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification

  validate :validate_card, :on => :create

  def validate_card
    unless credit_card.valid?
      credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        errors.add_to_base "error"
      end
    end
  end

    def credit_card
    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
      :type               => card_type,
      :number             => card_number,
      :verification_value => card_verification,
      :month              => card_expires_on.month,
      :year               => card_expires_on.year,
      :first_name         => first_name,
      :last_name          => last_name
    )
  end
```

it is pointing to `Undefined method add_to_base`

Answer (score 86, accepted):

`add_to_base` method was removed from rails 3. You should use `errors[:base] << "error"` instead.

Comment: See Brad Werth's answer below for alternate syntax.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the following, over the accepted answer:

`errors.add :base, 'error message'`

Comment: Yep, me too. It makes sense to use the same syntax as other errors.

Answer (score 2):

In your model just make:

```
:add_to_base=> false
```

Access it in your controller as:

```
model_instance.errors.messages
```